# Load all the effect of storyboard until it's finish

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image which when pressed by user, the opacity will fade until value 0. But the effect only continues if user press and hold the image. Is there a possible way to change the code to: When user press, and without holding the press, the opacity fading effect will stay? I wish to do it in XAML.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="press">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource showA}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>

<Button Grid.Column="5" Command="{Binding Path=PressC}" CommandParameter="dot" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Name="image5" Source="/W;component/Images/t.png" Height="100" />
                            <Image Name="pressed5" Source="/W;component/Images/T.png" Height="100" Width="200" Margin="-23,-136,-21,0" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">          
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="pressed5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1.5" From="1" To="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="999"/>                           
                                <Setter TargetName="pressed5" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>                                    
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your full xaml? Because Image does not have IsPressed property and it is not clear how it works for you.
Similar code for button works as expected:

```
<Button Background="Aquamarine">
<Button.Style>
  <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1.5" From="1" To="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

And for Image it works too with EventTrigger:

```
<Image Source="d:\123.png">
<Image.Style>
  <Style TargetType="Image">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">            
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1.5" From="1" To="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>            
      </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Comment: Ok, now i see the problem. Your pressed5 image is visible only then button is pressed (`<Setter TargetName="pressed5" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>` works only while Button.IsPresssed=True). So when user stops pressing button, image becomes invisible and you don't see results of animation. I would try to set Opacity not Visibility by trigget but i am not sure which effect you want to achieve.

Comment: Omg if set `<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">` to `Value="False"`, it works! Thx man. Actually my image works like this: There are 2 images, 2nd image is hidden. When l click the 1st image, 2nd image will appear and will be fading away in few seconds.